# Conflict between Slick slider and Wordpress admin bar

Tags: slideshow

I'm using the Slick slider in my theme https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and Material design lite https://getmdl.io/

Problem I am having is that the transforms used here are conflicting with the Wordpress admin bar and causing it to disappear. If I comment these out it works better, but still disappears if the slide is in transition to the next slide.

```
.slick-slider .slick-list, .slick-slider .slick-track {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

}

I've tried setting useTransform to false on slick but that didn't help.

Comment: Try adjusting the admin bar z-index so it and the drop downs are in front of the slider.

Comment: Cool. If you move the solution into an answer that'll keep the site format tidy. In a couple of days you can accept your own answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a css rule for #wpadminbar:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
background: black;
width: 100%;
```

Makes the bar appear and

I added z-index: 0; to .mdl-layout__header to make the dropdowns appear.

Not the prettiest.

Answer (score 0):

insert this into your style.css:

```
body #wpadminbar{z-index:99;}
```

and maybe this solves.